# Settings for creating a whitelabel service

Tags: apache, cpanel, cname

I am trying to create a whitelabel service for my site. I want to do it like dohop does. So I created a sub domain on my main site like : whitelabel.example.com and I want to know what I have to do in order for a user to be able to set a cname on his domain to use my service.

I tried this:

```
User's domain: userdomain.com
tests.userdomain.com - CNAME - whitelabel.example.com
www.tests.userdomain.com - CNAME - whitelabel.example.com
```

When I ping tests.userdomain.com I get:

```
Pinging to whitelabel.example.com
```

So I guess the CNAME does it's job but I can't figure out what I have to do on my server (example.com) in order to understand and reply to the request.

All I get when i type tests.userdomain.com in my browser is cpanel's default page that informs me of an error.

Answer (score 0):

If you was using PHP for instance you could do:

```
<?php
    $host = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] : $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
    $host = str_replace('.example.com','',$host);
    echo $host;
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Once your CNAME as has setup, you need to use your sub domain into iframe so that when any visitor make a search, they will land to your subdomain which is pointed to dohop affiliate server. Hope this help!

Thanks